# How to implement 2 factor authentication in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, 2-step-verification

Can anyone please mention how to implement 2 factor authentication in Sharepoint 2010?

I have been reading alot of stuff. but can not figure out what exactly should I do first.

Can anyone atleast mention the steps to implement 2 factor authentication.

Comment: I think you'd reap more benefit in implementing ADFS and use claims based auth http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx

Comment: Yes even i came across this link. And I think it will be good to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an http module where you can redirect all your users who have successfully passed the first authentication step (windows auth or forms auth) to a second authentication page (ex: to enter averification code that was sent by sms)

Only after the second step is successfully passed the users can enter the system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to implement it in SharePoint itself. ADFS can sound tempting since it is easy to implement it over there, but be aware that there are many other pitfalls that come with it (Check what happens to user lookups in the people picker for example)

Another option is to implement something on a NLB that is capable of doing a preauth (incl a 2nd factor) before the user is reaching SharePoint. This allows to run SharePoint without modifying anything and reuse the (same) solution in the whole company.

Answer (score 0):

Configure 2FA for SharePoint

Click on Edit against the application you have configured. Enable the Enable 2-Factor Authentication (MFA) option. Click on Save.

Greetings,
Peter